# Bridge of tokens to L2?

Tags: erc-20, layer-2, bridge, polygon-bridge

I am developing erc20 tokens and Dapps.
If we can issue tokens to ethereum and when they are moved (e.g. when we move tokens according to Dapps rules) we can use polygonZkEVM or optimism with high scalability, which is something we favour.
We would like to achieve this at all costs, but we have no idea how to do it. So I would like to know about the following points.

1. the most common ways to realise such an idea.
2. case studies for reference.
3. whether such an idea is unnecessary in the first place and whether deploying erc20 tokens in polygon zkEVM or optimism is sufficient

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use any [open permissionless bridge](https://www.alchemy.com/list-of/web3-bridges-on-polygon) to move your tokens.

Note that bridged tokens have their own smart contract code running on L2, not your code.

> whether such an idea is unnecessary in the first place and whether deploying erc20 tokens in polygon zkEVM or optimism is sufficient

Unless there is a reason you want your tokens on Ethereum mainnet, you can directly deploy them on any alternative L2.